# Animate function jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new here and I have a problem with the jQuery's function - "animate"

```
function myFunction(newpage) {
$('#loader').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 400, 'linear', function(){
    // callback of fadeOut()
    $(this).load(newpage + ".php #toload", function(){
        // callback of load()
        $('#loader').animate({opacity: 100.0}, 400, 'linear', function(){
            //callback of fadeIn()
            // (not relevant for my problem, I think)
            $.getScript("js/test.js");
        });
      });
   });
}
```

My problem is: the first "animate" works like a charm but the second "animate" loads the new content correctly, without the animation (a simple "fadeIn").

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advice!

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation is working but it is so fast that you can't see it because you have specified `opacity:100;` in 400 millisecond

use `{opacity: 1;}` because opacity maximum value is 1 and min. value is 0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Don't forget to click on the left side check mark of this answer

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check something like this

```
$('#loader').hide().fadeIn(400, function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: But I want to load a content between the `hide()` and the `fadeIn()`